# reversing scale colour gradient in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2's `scale_colour_gradient2` to have a color gradient scale for numbers from 1 to 20 using:

```
geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=c)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(lims=c(1, 20), high="red", low="grey")
```

The problem is that this puts value at 1 as white, and values at 20 as red, and I'd like to reverse this (smaller values in the `c` column for colour are more red than higher values. How can I do this? If I reverse `low` and `high` in `scale_colour_gradient2` it just gives a purpose gradient which is not what I intended. thanks.

Comment: Where does "grey" come into it? Sounds like you just want to use `scale_colour_gradient()`

Comment: @alexwhan: I just want it to fade from red to white

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "white")
```

scale_colour_gradient2 is for a symmetrical gradient.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the color variable, insert a minus sign

```
p <- ggplot(temphunt, aes(x=Time.dec, y=TEMP..C., colour=-mod1.residuals)) +   scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(10))
```

Will reverse the rainbow scale, relative to leaving the minus sign out